# Only when I deactivate Woocommerce I can access the widgets - why is that?

Tags: woocommerce, widget

After I while I wanted to access the "widget" area on my woocommerce site.

I got then this message:

***Es gab einen kritischen Fehler auf Ihrer Website. Bitte überprüfen Sie den Posteingang Ihrer Website-Administrator-E-Mail-Adresse für weitere Anweisungen.

Erfahren Sie mehr über die Problembehandlung in WordPress.***

So I deactivated all the plugins, and still I could't access it. I then deactivated woocommerce and it worked.

I got this message by mail:

WordPress-Version 6.3.1
Aktives Theme: Thelma Child (Version 1.0.0)
Aktuelles Plugin:  (Version )
PHP-Version 7.4.33

## Fehler-Details

Ein Fehler vom Typ E_ERROR wurde in der Zeile 37 der Datei /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/thelma/framework/modules/woocommerce/widgets/woocommerce-dropdown-cart/woocommerce-dropdown-cart.php verursacht. Fehlermeldung: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/thelma/framework/modules/woocommerce/widgets/woocommerce-dropdown-cart/woocommerce-dropdown-cart.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(394): ThelmaMikadoClassWoocommerceDropdownCart->widget(Array, Array)
#1 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-includes/widgets.php(2026): WP_Widget->display_callback(Array, Array)
#2 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(697): wp_render_widget('mkdf_woocommerc...', 'wine-shop-right')
#3 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(154): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->prepare_item_for_response(Array, Object(WP_REST_Request))
#4 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1188): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->get_items(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#5 /home/gallovin/public_html/test/w

I was searching for it on google. It seems that some people have similar problems. But not quit the same. Therefore I wasn't able to solve it yet.

What I did so far:

I updated all the plugins
Delted the cache
Under Woocommerce - statuts - tools I emptied the customer session and transients.

Anyone a good idea?

Comment: The error message you are getting is actually telling you where the problems occurs, on `line 37` in the file `woocommerce-dropdown-cart.php`. The problem is `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null`. 

You should contact the Theme/Plugin author to inform that it might be good to check that the object passed to `get_cart()` isn’t null, to avoid this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and writing me. It's much appreciated.
What I wasn't sure if it's a woocommerce or theme problem. But then it's the theme that causes this.

So there isn't something that I could change on woocommerce or the theme to fix it?